# How to get only positive integers in array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating an array with integers given by users. However, I only need positive integers. How do I check a user entered integer to see if it is positive?

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     Integer array [] = new Integer[10];
     int userChoice;
     boolean loop = true;

     // to loop through the switch and show userChoice to user until chose to 
     // quit

     System.out.println("Please enter the 10 positive integers to be represented in the BST:");

     for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) 
         array[i] = input.nextInt(); 
}
```

I tried doing `if (input.nextInt() > 0)` inside the `for` loop but the program just freezes and doesn't do anything when I press enter. Also tried putting the `for` loop in `do while (input.nextInt() > 0)`, but I still experienced the same problem.

Comment: You are missing a fundamental concept of how this code is a. supposed to work and; b. how this code is actually working. Instead of begging someone to fix your problem, spend some time trying to understand what these control structures do, what you are trying to do, and why it's not working. Psudocode your solution out then come back to writing code. It will not help you if we just solve your problem because you won't understand why it fixes your issue.

Comment: Sounds good, but no body begging here.

Comment: You said that you tried inserting an if inside the for loop but the program froze. That is actually leaning towards how to solve this issue. You need to work out WHY it froze and where it froze.

Comment: You don't show any *actual* code  but mention "I tried doing `if (input.nextInt() > 0)` " ... well, what do you *think* that's doing, exactly? Where's the number you just read from the input gone? What are you doing after that? Maybe that's the problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something straightforward like

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    int check = input.nextInt();
    if (check > 0)
        array[i] = check;
    else {
        System.out.println("Only positives, try again.");
        i--;
    }
}
```

However, you can be more creative and I suggest you really try to.